# What does the error relation "demographic_types" does not exist mean?

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to truncate the data from the pgsql database and then trying to insert the data from the csv file , below code is able to truncate the data , but while trying to copy it fails with the below error

> "OUT Error Code: 42P01. Error ERROR:  relation "demographic_types" does not exist"

```
for fle in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"database/data/*.csv"))):
print ('>>>Migrating data %s' % fle)
table_name = os.path.basename(fle).replace('.csv', '')

    try:
        #silent_query(conn, sql, None)
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
        #delete data first
        print('Deleting data from table  %s' % table_name)
        cur.execute('TRUNCATE %s CASCADE' % table_name)

        with open(fle, 'r') as f:
        #headers = ", ".join(table_column_mapping_data[table_name])
        print("i am here open")
        sql = "COPY %s from STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER AS ','" % table_name
        print(sql)
        cur.copy_expert(sql, f)
        conn.commit()
        except Exception as exp:
        print ('Error Code: %s. Error %s' % (exp.pgcode, exp.pgerror))
```

How do I solve that error?

Comment: Is it failing at `TRUNCATE` or at `COPY`? Can you paste the actual output somewhere?

Comment: You can do consistency check for name of csv file and table. You can also check user schema in which the table exists.

Comment: @richyen it fails at copy , before that i have truncate it worked on the same table but copy fails

Comment: @KIM table exist thats how it is able to truncate but copy fails for same table

Comment: @richyen>>>Migrating data /home/vcap/app//database/data/demographic_types.csv
   2019-11-29T12:39:04.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 100 Deleting data from table  demographic_types
   2019-11-29T12:39:04.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Error Code: 42P01. Error ERROR:  relation "demographic_types" does not exist
   2019-11-29T12:39:04.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT load ROCC db updates and data complete 2019-11-29 07:09:04.709468
   2019-11-29T12:39:04.70+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ***DATABASE MIGRATION SUCCESSFUL***

Comment: Seems like it fails on truncate—it never prints out “I am here open”